# Searching SAS data sets from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, sas

I am trying to find a way to search a sas7bdat file from excel for a specific value, and then copy and paste the data into an excel spreadsheet. Currently I can add the whole data set and then search it in excel, but it would be much better if I could search the data set before adding it to excel, as the data sets are sometimes too large for excel to handle.

Is there a way of doing this? Or alternatively is there a way of running some SAS code from excel that would perform the search for me?

Many thanks,

Alastair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS has a Microsoft Office add-in that you can use to connect to SAS datasets from excel.  See their [product page](http://support.sas.com/software/products/addin/) for more information.

There are a few other options for connecting to SAS as a data source; you can use ODBC for example.  You also can do what you describe using [DDE](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ddeexamples.htm).  Finally, you can produce excel spreadsheets (but not paste into particular spots, easily anyway) using PROC EXPORT or ODS EXCEL (the latter in 9.4 TS1M2+).  You can filter the dataset to the appropriate size prior to exporting.